# t Google Keyboard gesture typing intermittently stopping after switching keyboards

Tags: keyboard, gboard, gesture-typing

Sometimes when I switch keyboards (from Google Pinyin input) back to English the gesture (Swype) typing doesn't work. There may also be a several second delay when switching. Occasionally the app I'm using loses its bottom half to a glitchy-looking keyboard. The problem goes away on its own after some time has passed or after force-quitting the app that was open when switching.

This problem is present on both a Nexus 4 and Nexus 6 running Lollipop and Marshmallow respectively.